# how to fix sum of entered even numbers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

i just wrote this code using C language and run successfully but i tried to write in Javascript it doesnt work .......

thanks !!!!

```js
function addNumbers(){
     var a = Number(document.getElementById("num1").value);
  var b = Number(document.getElementById("num2").value);
  var c = Number(document.getElementById("num3").value);
  var d = Number(document.getElementById("num4").value);
  var e = Number(document.getElementById("num5").value);
  var sum = document.getElementById("answer").value;
  if (var a%2==0){
            var sum = var sum + var a;
        }

        if (var b%2==0){
            var sum = var sum + var b;
        }

        if (var c%2==0){
            var sum = var sum + var c;
        }

        if (var d%2==0){
            var sum = var sum + var d;
        }

        if (var e%2==0){
            var sum = var sum + var e;
        }
     }
```

```html
    <table>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input class="txt" id="num1">
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input class="txt" id="num2">
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td><input class="txt" id="num3">
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td><input class="txt" id="num4">
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td><input class="txt" id="num5">
   </tr>
   <tr>
    
    <td><input type="button" name="Sumbit" value="+" onclick="addNumbers()"/>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>SUM:</td>
    <td><input class="txt" id="answer">
   </tr>
   </table>
```

html code

Comment: Did you get the expected result when you did a console log of the a,b,c etc values? also, you only need to use the var sum once. From looking at your code, there are a lot of issues. What is the answers element value, why are you setting sum to be the value of it if you are wanting it to be the sum of the even numbers? So many questions..

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: I know precious little Javascript, but from what little I know, `var` introduces a (certain type of) variable *declaration*. So you should drop all the `var`s where only *using* existing variables.

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: C tag removed. Not sure if the html tag should be removed as well.

Comment: Does the declaration for `sum` need to be cast to a number – `var sum = Number(document.getElementById("answer").value)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your complete code and it works now

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td><input class="txt" id="num1">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><input class="txt" id="num2">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td><input class="txt" id="num3">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td><input class="txt" id="num4">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td><input class="txt" id="num5">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input name="Sumbit" onclick="addNumbers()" type="button" value="+"/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>SUM:</td>
        <td><input class="txt" id="answer">
    </tr>
</table>
</body>

<script>
    function addNumbers() {
        console.log("avc")
        var a = Number(document.getElementById("num1").value);
        var b = Number(document.getElementById("num2").value);
        var c = Number(document.getElementById("num3").value);
        var d = Number(document.getElementById("num4").value);
        var e = Number(document.getElementById("num5").value);
        var sum = 0;
        console.log(typeof a)
        if (a%2==0)
             sum +=  a;
        if ( b%2==0)
            sum +=  b;
        if ( c%2==0)
            sum +=  c;
        if ( d%2==0)
            sum +=  d;
        if ( e%2==0)
            sum +=  e;
        document.getElementById("answer").value = sum;
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you can you explain for me we you used console.log()??

Comment: Ignore it, it's just for checking, you can remove it

Answer (score 0):

do not add 'var' before every variable name, you have to declare it only once.

```
function addNumbers()
{
  var a = Number(document.getElementById("num1").value);
  var b = Number(document.getElementById("num2").value);
  var c = Number(document.getElementById("num3").value);
  var d = Number(document.getElementById("num4").value);
  var e = Number(document.getElementById("num5").value);
  var sum = document.getElementById("answer").value;
  if (a%2==0)
  {
    sum = sum + a;
  }
  if (b%2==0)
  {
    sum = sum + b;
  }
  if (c%2==0)
  {
    sum = sum + c;
  }
  if (d%2==0)
  {
    sum = sum + d;
  }
  if (e%2==0)
  {
    sum = sum + e;
  }
}
```

Comment: i know but this is not the issue

Comment: the elements num1, num2 ... are input? if so, what is their type? if the type is 'text' try with: `Number.parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value, 10)` instead of `Number(document.getElementById("num1").value)`

Answer (score 0):

try not to declare var again.
Just add on it not do that

```
 if (var d%2==0){
     var sum = var sum + var d;
  }
```

Do this

```
 if (var d%2==0){
     sum += d;
  }
```

for every condition

Comment: ok same answer like before this is not the problem i know all these Assignment

Comment: If that is so, why did you do it?

Comment: any suggestion ?

Comment: The what is the problem

Comment: `<table>
   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input class="txt" id="num1">
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input class="txt" id="num2">
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td><input class="txt" id="num3">
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td><input class="txt" id="num4">
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td><input class="txt" id="num5">
   </tr>
   <tr>
    
    <td><input type="button" name="Sumbit" value="+" onclick="addNumbers()"/>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>SUM:</td>
    <td><input class="txt" id="answer">
   </tr>
   </table> `

Comment: @feyizbeik, can you put this html code in the question itself?

Comment: Ok, let me perform this

Answer (score 0):

You could collect all values in an array by using the id of the inputs directly as variable with their value property and reduce this by checking and adding the value.

```js
function calc() {
    sum.innerHTML = [num1.value, num2.value, num3.value, num4.value, num5.value]
        .reduce((s, v) => s + (v % 2 === 0 && +v), 0);
}
```

```html
<input id="num1" type="text"><br>
<input id="num2" type="text"><br>
<input id="num3" type="text"><br>
<input id="num4" type="text"><br>
<input id="num5" type="text"><br>
<button onclick="calc();">calc</button><br>
Even Sum: <span id="sum">0</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

There were quite a few errors in your code, but i made a snippet below with a functional implementation:

```js
//Create HTML Elements
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var label = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("label"));
    label.innerHTML = "Number " + i + ": ";
    var input = label.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
    input.type = "number";
    input.id = "num" + i;
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
}
var resultField = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("input"));
resultField.id = "answer";
//Sum function
function addNumbers() {
    var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value) || 0;
    var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num2").value) || 0;
    var c = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num3").value) || 0;
    var d = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num4").value) || 0;
    var e = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num5").value) || 0;
    var sum = 0;
    if (a % 2 == 0) {
        sum = sum + a;
    }
    if (b % 2 == 0) {
        sum = sum + b;
    }
    if (c % 2 == 0) {
        sum = sum + c;
    }
    if (d % 2 == 0) {
        sum = sum + d;
    }
    if (e % 2 == 0) {
        sum = sum + e;
    }
    document.getElementById("answer").value = sum;
}
//Create button and bind events
var btn = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("button"));
btn.innerHTML = "Calculate";
btn.addEventListener("click", addNumbers);
```

Errors to take into account:

1. Don't re-declare variables with `var` every time you use them.
2. When get numbers from user input in JavaScript, be prepared to handle `NaN` values.
3. Variables isn't two-way binding. Declare `sum` as a numeric value `0` and send that value to your `html` element, when you are done calculating it.